# jquery: grab div title attr, put it into the image src

Tags: jquery, attributes, variables

I'm creating a lightbox for a website I'm creating, and no, I don't want to use one already made, I want to make my own.

When the user clicks on a `<span>` somewhere on the website, I have jquery grab that `<span>`'s title attribute, and stick it into an image src, and then inject that image tag into `.overlay_content`.

Everything works except it wont grab the title, the variable doesn't work and I don't know what I did wrong. It's inserting grabbed-img into the src for the image, not the title of the `span.overlay_img`

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.overlay_img').click(function (){
            var docHeight = $(document).height();
            var grabbed_img = $(this).attr('title'); 

            $(".overlay_bg").height(docHeight).fadeIn(300, function(){
                $(".overlay_content").html("<img src='grabbed_img'>").fadeIn(300); 
                });
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not grabbing the title? Have you tried an alert to test it?

`alert(grabbed_img)`

Looks like it might be an issue with this line:

```
        $(".overlay_content").html("<img src='grabbed_img'>").fadeIn(300);
```

Should be:

```
        $(".overlay_content").html("<img src='" + grabbed_img + "'>").fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: ah you guys both got it, excellent, i didn't know i had to put those extra quotes in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on line 7 of your script:

```
(".overlay_content").html("<img src='" + grabbed_img + "'>").fadeIn(300);
```

There's no variable interpolation of the type you attempt in JavaScript. You need to build the string up using the concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

its not grabbing the title because your not directing it to grab the image's title, your directing it to grab the div's title, and it has none.

```
    $('.overlay_img img')
```

Comment: The OP _wanted_ the div's title, not the image's title. The marked answer explains the problem, which was a problem with forming the new html.